# Unhandled exception at 0x0F6F8EF7 (msvcr120d.dll) 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x091C5B30

Tags: c

i'm trying to write to txt file but after the program write almost the whole text, i get the next error:

> **Unhandled exception at 0x0F6F8EF7 (msvcr120d.dll) 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x091C5B30.**

trace set as:

```
trace = fopen("trace.txt", "w");
```

arr set as:

```
int arr[18]; // (also all of the arr values initial to zero.)

for (i = 0; i < 18; i++){
    fprintf(trace, "%08x ", arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run a debug-build in a debugger to catch the crash in action, so you can locate exactly where it happens in your code? And when it happens examine the involved variables to make sure they are all okay? Perhaps you should take some time to read about [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that `trace` is an invalid `FILE*`  because the file couldn't be opened for some reason. Please show how `trace` is initialized.

Comment: Or there may be a problem with `arr`. What is `arr`? How is it declared? How is it initialized?.

Comment: Also read this: [mcve].

Comment: arr set as : int arr[18] (arr values initial to zero), trace: Files *trace; ,   trace = fopen("trace.txt", "w")

Comment: @Vini the code you posted looks fine. Either `fopen` returns `NULL` because the file cannot be opened for some reason, or the problem is in the part of your code you didn't show. `fprintf` on a NULL pointer is UB and usually leads to a crash.

Answer (score 2):

My guess here would be that the **loop** is iterating more than intended causing the **arr[i]** to be out of its fixed size. Other than that the problem might be in the trace initialization. Provide information regarding those please!

This worked for me:

```
int i;
int mark[5] = {19, 10, 8, 17, 9};
FILE *trace = fopen("C:\\trace.txt", "w");
if (trace == NULL)
{
      printf("Error opening file!\n");
}
for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
    fprintf(trace,"%d ", mark[i]);

}
fclose(trace);
```

**Result:**

[image]

**After post Updated:**
To properly iterate over arr[18] your for loop should look like this:

```
for(i = 0; i <= 17; i++)
```

That is because when you define array with 18 elements you can use the memebers from arr[0] to arr[17].

If you look at my example above, here is the same snippet result but when you run the for loop like this:

```
for(i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
```

Note I have changed *i <= 4* to *i <= 5*;

**Result:**

[image]

As you can see we are accessing elements outside array's bounds, causing the program to write garbage in the text file.